# Time dependent Workflow - converting lead

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have a time dependent workflow on a lead date field, i.e. if a lead is inactive for 30 days, then change the status field to inactive and reassign to an "unassigned leads" queue. The problem is, that if I have this time based workflow on my lead, I cannot convert this lead! Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed workaround this problem. There is a similar question already [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-queued-time-based-workflow-using-apex). But basically you will need somehow to delete the pending action from the time-based workflow queue before to convert your lead. For example, you can update a field that will reevaluate the criteria and cancel the time based workflow.