# Error invoking web service callout from button

Tags: webservices, callout

I am invoking a web service callout from a buttons below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/apex.js")}
sforce.apex.execute("ClientPortal_lead","Lead_Approval", {email:"{!Lead.Email}"});
window.alert("Data sent to Client Portal" );
window.location.reload();
```

Class for invoking webservice:

```
global class ClientPortal_lead{
  WebService  static void Lead_Approval(String email) {
       comAdssClientportalSfapi.ClientServiceSoap11 stub = new comAdssClientportalSfapi.ClientServiceSoap11();
       comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse approveResponse = stub.Approval(email);
       if(!approveResponse.success) {
         throw new LeadConversionException(approveResponse.errorCode);
       }
  }
}
```

Part of class generated from WSDL class generatedfrom WSDL

```
public class ClientServiceSoap11 {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://my.ads-securities.com/client-portal-web/endpoints';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x = 'London_CP';
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://com/adss/clientportal/sfapi', 'comAdssClientportalSfapi'};
        public comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionResponse Rejection(String emailAddress) {
            comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionRequest request_x = new comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionRequest();
            request_x.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionResponse response_x;
            Map<String, comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://com/adss/clientportal/sfapi',
              'RejectionRequest',
              'http://com/adss/clientportal/sfapi',
              'RejectionResponse',
              'comAdssClientportalSfapi.RejectionResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }

public comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse Approval(String emailAddress) {
            comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalRequest request_x = new comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalRequest();
            request_x.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse response_x;
            Map<String, comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://com/adss/clientportal/sfapi',
              'ApprovalRequest',
              'http://com/adss/clientportal/sfapi',
              'ApprovalResponse',
              'comAdssClientportalSfapi.ApprovalResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x;
        }
```

Error Mesaage:

> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'System.CalloutException: Web
>   service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault:
>   WebApplicationException [locale=null, username=null, messages=[An
>   error has occurred], cause=null] faultcode=SOAP-ENV:Server faultactor=
>
> Class.comAdssClientportalSfapi.ClientServiceSoap11.Approval: line 312,
>   column 1 Class.ClientPortal_lead.Lead_Approval: line 11, column 1', }

Comment: Do you have to set the cert or password?

Comment: No @eric, we have not applied any security.  I was debugging further and found out that that , we get the error only when record is in in time based workflow queue. Is there a reason for this and how can we overcome this?

Comment: By design SFDC prevents leads from converting if they are in a time-based workflow queue; see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004995&language=en_US and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55684/time-dependent-workflow-converting-lead and Idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpPQAA0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design SFDC prevents leads from converting if they are in a time-based workflow queue; see

- [Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004995&language=en_US)
- A workaround (involving setting a field that terminates the time-based workflow, [is given here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-queued-time-based-workflow-using-apex)
- An Idea to change behavior is [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpPQAA0)

You'll probably want to detect that the Lead is in a time-based workflow and if Lead Conversion request comes in, force the Lead out of the time-based workflow using the workaround above before submitting the lead Conversion DML (or whatever makes sense for your business process)