# Dangers of mass deleting objects from time-based workflow queue

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

We deactivated a faulty rule and now have to delete about 30,000 objects from our time-based workflows queue. Anyone know of any risks/encountered any bugs while deleting on such a scale?

Comment: Easiest way to delete them all would be here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-queued-time-based-workflow-using-apex

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all pending actions to be triggered on a future date appear in the Workflow Queue. Here's how System administrators can view and manage the queue: Go to Setup | Customize | Monitor | Time-Based Workflow and delete the action which you don't want to fire.